# drupal comment link to user profile

Tags: drupal, comments

I can see Drupal comments have a link to user's profile (the commenter) when I am logged in. But as anonymous visitor I can not see that link.
I want to make the link working for all visitor. So that the visitor can go to the user's page by clicking it. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you checked the *View user profiles* permission for the anonymous user role? By default it is unchecked. Once it is checked that role, the username becomes a link for anonymous users as well.

Comment: +++ Thanks a lot. Now I can remember this permission was disabled. But now I am not in administration of the site. The new admin changed the password and I do not want to ask him. I have access to the server and files. So I am thinking about directly edit the code for it. I guess there will be a TRUE/FALSE type setting somewhere. Can you help me this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you may access the database. Why don't you try to make yourself an administrator role?

The data save in users_roles table. Find your uid and change the rid to administrator[maybe it's 3].

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the database directly however its really not recommended under any conditions. You can however use drush to change the role of a user. [Review this page](http://www.codejourneymen.com/content/adding-admin-user-drupal-site-without-overwriting-admin-user).